# How do I fix a zfs boot problem: error: no such device

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, zfs

I needed to free up some space in bpool to add the latest patches to my Ubuntu 22.04 system running ZFS.  I tried to ZFS destroy the oldest snapshot, and upon reboot, booting failed with the following:

```
Booting a command list

error: no such device: 9a3acf1a88182eec.  
Loading Linux 6.2.0-34-generic ...  
error: file '/BOOT/ubuntu_uad4uk@/vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic' not found  
Loading initial ramdisk ...  
error: you need to load the kernel first.  

Press any key to continue...
```

How do I fix my system without destroying my data and rpool?  What is the device `9a3acf1a88182eec`?  I am a long-time Unix (Solaris) user, but not very familiar with Ubuntu admin or grub.

I originally installed from the live disk, and it created the bpool and rpool zfs pools, and booted from an EFI partition on a nvram disk.

I have tried booting Ubuntu Live from a USB and can import, mount, and look at the bpool ZFS.  All of the kernels I had are there, including all the files/directories that were visible from the bpool mounted on the /boot directory before the problem.  I can also mount the EFI partition and see the grub stuff, so I think all of the files I had before are not missing.

The grub entry that gave the above message is:

```
setparams 'Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, with Linux 6.2.0-34-generic'  
    recordfail  
    load_video  
    gfxmode ${linux_gfx_mode}  
    insmod gzio  
    if [ "${grub_platform}" = xen ] ; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi  
    insmod part_gpt  
    insmod zfs  
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9a3acf1a88182eec  
    echo Loading Linux 6.2.0-34-generic ...  
    linux "/BOOT/ubuntu_uad4uk@/vmlinuz-6.2.0-34-generic" root=ZFS="rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ad4uk" l_iommu=on,igfx_off quiet splash ${vt_handoff}  
    echo 'Loading initial ramdisk ...'  
    initrd "/BOOT/ubuntu_uad4uk@/initrd.img-6.2.0-34-generic"
```

I have tried to follow the suggestion of @Daniel T, and update-grub gives

```
/# update-grub  
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'  
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'  
Generating grub configuration file ...  
grub-probe: error: compression algorithm inherit not supported
.  
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting  
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.  
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.  
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.  
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...  
done
```

When I run grub-install, I get:

```
/# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi       --bootloader-id=ubuntu --recheck —no-floppy  
  
 Installing for x86_64-efi platform.  
grub-install: error: compression algorithm inherit not supported
```

Comment: You may boot Ubuntu from LiveCD or LiveUSB to seek what was the problem withour destroying your data. You would want to see your `grub.cfg` .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: What you did to ZFS might have changed around the partition numbers. Reinstalling GRUB from LiveCD should help.

Comment: @Daniel T  I tried to set up  my /mnt root filesystem as instructed in the grub repair answer, modifying for the ZFS bpool and rpool I have.  I was able to mount the / ZFS filesystem in the rpool on /mnt and the bpool ZFS filesystem on /mnt/boot.  When I tried to mount /mnt/var and /mnt/usr from the rpool ZFS filesystems I got a "canmount is off" error.  I set canmount to "on" and was able to mount, but the filesystems show no files and update-grub fails.  I am certain that the data on those filesystems was not deleted.  How do I reinstall GRUB from a LiveUSB?